# Is it benefical to initialize variables with null/empty values before assigning "real" values?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to update an older data dictionary module at my new workplace. I have some code that seems superfluous but I'm not sure if it is in place because of a 'best practice' or perhaps some other reason that I don't know.

```
SqlCommand objSQLCommand = null;
string strquery = string.Empty;
strquery = string.Format("SELECT Name FROM sys.databases ORDER BY name");
objSQLCommand = new SqlCommand(strquery);
```

It seems to me like this could be done in two lines (at most), but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Yes... You can do it in two lines... This might be your project coding guildlines to write code like this, but your variable names are terrible as @CamiloTerevinto mentioned in his comment

Comment: Unnecessary code with terrible variable names

Comment: One line would be plenty. var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT...");

Comment: This is unnecessary and actually actively harmful if done throughout the code base, because it robs the compiler of a chance to issue errors about uninitialized local variables. Those are very much preferable to `NullReferenceException`s (for `null`) and silent failures (for `string.Empty`). Also, if `string.Format` is used consistently for queries, take a long hard look at the rest of the code and how it treats parameters -- you may well find that it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Could be a one-liner if you really like. `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM sys.databases ORDER BY name");`. But it's somewhat a matter of opinion and style really. There's no right or wrong answer, although Jeroen's comments about initialising the variable with pointless values which are immediately over-written is very valid.

Comment: It's both disappointing and exciting when you realize that the person who came before you didn't know what he was doing. Disappointing because you realize that you're not going to learn much from following their examples, but exciting because you can recognize it.

Comment: Unnecessary code, but I like the variable names.

Comment: Incidentally, I see no instance of `using` here either. If the code does not call `Dispose` itself, that's another problem. It is very likely that everything going on in this module can be replaced with a few well-placed invocations of [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), with benefits to reliability, security and, if you're lucky, performance.

Answer (score 1):

For this query, `string.Format()` seems to be useless. It probably has been copied from another query with parameters in my opinion.
However `string.Format()` is still very bad to use parameters in a query. It can lead to [security issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2100-review-sql-queries-for-security-vulnerabilities?view=vs-2019).
What you can do to clean this code is :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM sys.databases ORDER BY name");
```

However, I strongly advise you to read some [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8) and to get the required knowledge to understand why use or not use parts of this code.